# Word order: "dear my lord" in Shakespeare

Tags: word-order, shakespeare

I'm revisiting my old question [#[167151]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167151/the-correct-word-order-in-dear-my-love). The original question was about the word order: “dear my love” or “my dear love”. I hold a position that we say “my dear love”.

But when I was saying a prayer yesterday, I heard myself say “dear my lord”, and it just sounded smooth to my ear. I looked up the phrase and I found it in *[Hamlet](http://m.sparknotes.com/nfs/hamlet/page_188.html)* by Shakespeare. That made me think, what was in my mind when I asked the former question.

The linked site above for *Hamlet* lists line-by-line translations into modern English and the page shows the following dialogue in Act 3, Scene 2, Page 2:

[Shakespeare] CLAUDIUS: Thanks, **dear my lord**.

[Translation] CLAUDIUS: Thanks, **my dear lord**.

And my question here is not about which order is correct. Instead I wonder: **If the word order was turned the other way around, when did the change occur, and why did it happen?**

Comment: Was it commonly that way round or was Shakespeare making a point about Claudius being awkward?

Comment: In King Lear, Act 5, Scene 1, Page 1, “REGAN: I never shall endure her. Dear my lord, Be not familiar with her.” In Othello, Act 3, Scene 3, Page 8, “IAGO: Good name in man and woman, dear my lord, Is the immediate jewel of their souls.”

Comment: In Julius Caesar, Act 2, Scene 1, Page 11, “PORTIA: I should not know you, Brutus. Dear my lord, Make me acquainted with your cause of grief.”

Comment: Consider that "m'lord" is a title.

Comment: That explains the translation is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the form appears to always have been "my dear X". It is now (unless you're writing a letter), and it was before Shakespeare's time. This can be seen in examples from Middle English, from [this entry in the Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED11195&egs=all&egdisplay=open) (emphasis added):

> And dele A-mong my Frendes · and **my deore children**.
>   <sub>[The vision of William concerning Piers the Plowman](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AJT8124.0001.001/131:3.8) (c1390)</sub>

> Luke it be done and delte to **my dere pople**
>   <sub>[Morte Arthur](https://books.google.com/books?id=i0wJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA36) (c1440)</sub>

> **My dere sonne**, I ȝef vp my sowle ynto þi hondes
>   <sub>[Mirk's Festial](https://books.google.com/books?id=1bQLAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA223) (a1500)</sub>

There are also examples of "my dear X" in Shakespeare's works, as can be seen [here](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/ss.cgi?q=my+dear&mode=k). So why "dear my X"? [Hot Licks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422361/x#comment1011120_422361) suggests that we "[c]onsider that "m'lord" is a title". I did find some evidence that "dear my lord/lady" was used by others, e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=b-YyAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1083) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=A1sJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA129) (but neither of these are particularly close to Shakespeare's time).

However, the bigger problem with this theory is that Shakespeare uses "dear my X" when "my X" is not a title (e.g. "dear my brother"), as you can see [here](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/ss.cgi?q=dear+my&mode=k). Looking into this, I found a possible explanation:

> Shakespeare occasionally uses a peculiar idiomatic phraseology similar to that employed in the Italian language. He sometimes thus transposes the adjective and the pronoun in a phrase.
>   <sub>[The Shakespeare Key](https://books.google.com/books?id=2wx66C5PejwC&pg=PA421)</sub>

The book gives many examples of this, including "dear my brother", "dear my lord", "gentle my lord", and "good my glass".

Comment: This is amazingly compelling. My heartfelt thanks to you.

Comment: +1 yet  see also my answer. I wonder *how* this phraseology is "similar to that employed in the Italian language". At any rate, both resources we proffer are from the 1870s.

Answer (score 4):

The famous work *A Shakespearean Grammar* (1870) by E. A. Abbott ([online here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0080%3Asection%3D1) and elsewhere)
should be consulted, even if it does not give the final word. Abbott considers that *my lord* is indeed at least treated as if it were one word, and likens it to the French *monsieur*.

On the [transposition of possessive adjectives](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0080%3Asection%3D4%3Asubsection%3D1%3Aparagraph%3D13)  (which I suggest you read) he writes

> The possessive Adjectives, when unemphatic, are sometimes transposed, being really combined with nouns (like the French *monsieur, milord*)

and proffers many examples, including

> dear my lord
>
> good my brother
>
> sweet my mother
>
> oh! Poor our sex
>
> good your highness
>
> good my knave
>
> good my friends
>
> good my mouse of virtue

Abbott writes

> It is possible that this use of "my," "our," &c. may be in part explained from their derivation, since they were originally not adjectives, but the possessive cases of pronouns.
>
> Thus, "sweet my mother," = "sweet mother of me," or "sweet mother mine."

Comment: Do you conclude that this phraseology is particular to the works of Shakespeare? Is it wrong for someone today to consider “my lord” a title or treat it as if it’s in one word? I can’t explain why I murmured to myself “dear my lord” while I knew that’s odd and peculiar, if not improper, because it also sounded smooth and rather natural to my ear.

Comment: I don't have any conclusions. And I wrote this answer mostly to give more (and perhaps different) information than is contained in @Laurel's great answer,  as to Shakespeare's use.

Comment: It's certainly not "wrong" to consider *my lord* or *my love*, etc as "one word" and to stick *dear* before it. I've made a comment about this under the answer by @Yohanes Khosiawan 许先汉. English allows plenty of artistic and grammatical license, especially in creative works.

Comment: I’m delighted to have such a sweet answer. It gives much more insights into the use of language by Shakespeare on this subject. And I feel relieved about my own usage of it.